# Dropdown Box Disappears When Using First Dropdown Box

Tags: python, tkinter, dropdown

My second dropdown box in my Tkinter Python Program disappears when selecting an option from the first one. You may have to increase the size of the window when opening the program.

It does work when separating them into different boxes, ie the first dropdown in box 'Box1R' and the second dropdown in 'Box2R', will work. However, In want them in the same box, so they can be next to each other.

Why is this occurring?

Thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
import os


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")


# create a frame for the boxes on the left
left_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="grey",)
left_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)
    

# add three boxes to the left frame
box1 = tk.Label(left_frame, text="Folder Location", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
box1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)
    
box2 = tk.Label(left_frame, text="IF", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
box2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)

box3 = tk.Label(left_frame, text="Then", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
box3.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)

# create a frame for the boxes on the left
right_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="grey")
right_frame.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True,padx=0, pady=0)

# add three boxes to the right frame

box1R = tk.Label(right_frame, text="", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
box1R.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True,padx=20, pady=10)
        
box2R = tk.Label(right_frame, text="", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
box2R.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)

# Create a list of options
options = ["File Name", "File Extension", "File Contents", "File Size", "Date Created", "Date Modified", "Date Accessed"]

# Create a StringVar to hold the selected option
selected_option = tk.StringVar()

# Set the initial option to the first option in the list
selected_option.set(options[0])

# Create a dropdown box with the options
dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(box2R, selected_option, *options)
    
dropdown.place(x=100, y=70)

# Create a list of options for the second dropdown box
options2 = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]

# Create a StringVar to hold the selected option for the second dropdown box
selected_option2 = tk.StringVar()

# Set the initial option to the first option in the list
selected_option2.set(options2[0])

# Create the second dropdown box with the options
dropdown2 = tk.OptionMenu(box2R, selected_option2, *options2)

# Position the second dropdown box to the right of the first one
dropdown2.place(x=200, y=70)
       
box3R = tk.Label(right_frame, text="", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
box3R.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)

# start the window
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the issue because you place the second dropdown box within the label. Using `place(x=200, y=70)`, tries to place it at a specific location. Instead, it would be best to use `pack()` or `grid()` to place it on the label. Here's an example using `pack()`:

```py
# Create the second dropdown box with the options
dropdown2 = tk.OptionMenu(box2R, selected_option2, *options2)

# Pack the second dropdown box within the label
dropdown2.pack(side="left", padx=20)
```

This way, you place the second dropdown box to the right of the first one within the label.

With that being said, your layout is giving me a terrible result. I would use a grid instead of using a pack.

Grid layout:
[Using Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmYx4.png)

Pack layout:
[Using Pack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs5RU.png)

Here is how I convert ur pack to grid:

```py
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")


# create a frame for the boxes on the left
left_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="grey",)
left_frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=False)
    

# add three boxes to the left frame
box1 = tk.Label(left_frame, text="Folder Location", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
box1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)
    
box2 = tk.Label(left_frame, text="IF", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
box2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)

box3 = tk.Label(left_frame, text="THEN", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
box3.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)

# create a frame for the boxes on the left
right_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="grey",)
right_frame.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=False)

# add three boxes to the right frame
box1R = tk.Label(right_frame, text="Folder Location", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
# box1R.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)
box1R.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

box2R = tk.Label(right_frame, text="IF", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
# box2R.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)
box2R.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

# Create a list of options
options = ["File Name", "File Extension", "File Contents", "File Size", "Date Created", "Date Modified", "Date Accessed"]

# Create a StringVar to hold the selected option
selected_option = tk.StringVar()

# Set the initial option to the first option in the list
selected_option.set(options[0])

# Create a dropdown box with the options
dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(box2R, selected_option, *options)
    
# dropdown.place(x=100, y=70)
dropdown.pack(side="left", padx=10)

# Create a list of options for the second dropdown box
options2 = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]

# Create a StringVar to hold the selected option for the second dropdown box
selected_option2 = tk.StringVar()

# Set the initial option to the first option in the list
selected_option2.set(options2[0])

# Create the second dropdown box with the options
dropdown2 = tk.OptionMenu(box2R, selected_option2, *options2)

# Position the second dropdown box to the right of the first one
# dropdown2.place(x=200, y=70)
dropdown2.pack(side="left", padx=10)
       
box3R = tk.Label(right_frame, text="", font=("Arial", 16), bg="white", fg="black")
# box3R.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)
box3R.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

# start the window
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Brenduan saying that ...However, In want them in the same box, so they can be next to each other.